# pandas: How to get first positive number?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
name    a    b    c
jack   -10  -6   -10
bill   -6   -3   -5
ray    -3   -12  -9 
pew     4   -23  -2  
shaun   12   3    2  
mitch   3    5    2
```

How can i make a new dataframe which takes the first positive value from each respective columns(a,b,c) and divides all the values in that column with that selected first positive value of that column and store the result of division in place of all the values. The output should look like this

```
name    a      b      c
jack   -10/4  -6/3   -10/2
bill   -6/4   -3/3   -5/2
ray    -3/4   -12/3  -9/2 
pew     4/4   -23/3  -2/2  
shaun   12/4   3/3    2/2  
mitch   3/4    5/3    6/2
```

Comment: Are each of these columns being sorted prior to you needing to find the first positive number?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way:

```
m=df.set_index('name')
final=m.div(m.mask(m.lt(0)).bfill().iloc[0]).reset_index()
```

---

```
    name     a         b    c
0   jack -2.50 -2.000000 -5.0
1   bill -1.50 -1.000000 -2.5
2    ray -0.75 -4.000000 -4.5
3    pew  1.00 -7.666667 -1.0
4  shaun  3.00  1.000000  1.0
5  mitch  0.75  1.666667  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check which values in the dataframe are greater than `0`, and take the `idxmax` (first True), then divide column-wise by the resulting values.

```
ix = df.loc[:,'a':].gt(0).idxmax()
df.loc[:,'a':] = df.loc[:,'a':].div(df.lookup(ix.values, ix.index))

   name     a         b    c
0   jack -2.50 -2.000000 -5.0
1   bill -1.50 -1.000000 -2.5
2    ray -0.75 -4.000000 -4.5
3    pew  1.00 -7.666667 -1.0
4  shaun  3.00  1.000000  1.0
5  mitch  0.75  1.666667  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`a/a.head(1)` (pandas broadcasting should take care of the rest)

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to solve OPs problem. To begin with, the `name` column is not the index, seems like another column, which can obviously not be divided